# why JPA Foriegn Key Related (@ManyToOne )Child objects are getting detached on persisting the parent object

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

My Child objects are getting detached once after the parent  object is persisted. on returning the parent object to view ,my child objects are null. To resolve this I'm fetching the object again  from database to process in the view.

//Pseudocode

Parent Entity

```
class Donor{
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private PreferredLanguage  preferredLanguage;
}
```

Child Entity

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package model.preferredlanguage;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

/**
 *
 * @author srikanth
 */
@Entity
public class PreferredLanguage  {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(nullable = false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(length=20)
    private String preferredLanguage;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPreferredLanguage() {
        return preferredLanguage;
    }

    public void setPreferredLanguage(String preferredLanguage) {
        this.preferredLanguage = preferredLanguage;
    }


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof PreferredLanguage)) {
            return false;
        }
        PreferredLanguage other = (PreferredLanguage) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Crntroller AddDonor Method

```
savedDonor = donorRepository.addDonor(donor);
```

Repository Method

```
  public Donor addDonor(Donor donor) {
    updateDonorAutomaticFields(donor);
    em.persist(donor);
    em.flush();
    return donor;
  }
```

Comment: -1 missing relevant code.

Comment: That is not possible unless you are missing something. Please add more details.

Comment: Sure, Let me edit adding code

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you mean by your child objects are detached?  Do you mean when you call persist, the relationship is set to null?  What was there and what do you expect to happen, and how have you read in the child objects or persisted them if they are new?

Answer (score -1):

Can you please provide code snippets,

My guess, your child objects may be of FetchType `FetchType.LAZY`

Comment: Should be a comment not an answer.